# Add items to a dynamic drop-down list based on cell value

Tags: excel, dropdown

This is a question about whether or not it is possible to do what I'm looking to do in excel.  I have a caselist sheet that looks like this:

[image]

And an encounter form that looks like this:

[image]

On the Encounter Sheet, I want to make a dropdown list that only contains names of people assigned to a specific case manager.  So, if I enter SH in the CM column, only those cases from the Caselist sheet where 'Assigned CM' is SH will populate the drop down menu.

Is this possible to do in Excel?  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the code given below.
The code assumes that you have two sheets in the workbook called "Encounter" and "CaseList". Headers on both the sheets are in row1. On Encounter Sheet, column A contains CM (a drop down to choose CM) and column B will have a dependent drop down list inserted by the code to choose the Names depending on the selected CM in col. A. On CaseList Sheet, Col. A is First Name, Col. B is Last Name and col. C is CM.

When above mentioned all the conditions are met, place the code given below on Encounter Sheet Module. To do so, right click on Encounter Tab --> View Code and place the code given below into the opened code window --> Close the VB Editor --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.
So after selecting a CM in col. A on Encounter Sheet as soon as you select the corresponding cell in col. B, the code will create a data validation list in that cell so you can choose the first name and last name separated by a space from the list. And once you select an item, the first name and last name will be entered in the cell separate by a comma.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim sws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, n As Long, i As Long
Dim x, dict
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sws = Sheets("CaseList")
lr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
x = sws.Range("A2:C" & lr).Value
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    n = Target.Offset(0, -1).Validation.Type
    If n = 3 Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            If x(i, 3) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                dict.Item(x(i, 1) & " " & x(i, 2)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        With Target.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                       xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(dict.keys, ",")
        End With
    End If
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Target <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Target.Value, " ", ", ", 1)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```